# Example of fluid layout

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Can you give example of some websites or tutorials with fluid layouts.

More importantly, I am looking for UI design which is fluid and gets easily extended to 
**both desktop and mobile/tablet browsers**
 (e.g. iPad)

Also any other best pracices for designing UI layouts which would work across desktop/mobile/tablet browsers.

When I say mobile, I am referring mainly to tablets with screen sizes of at least 7"

Please list as many examples as you could.

Comment: that's also a interesting place http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: this is not a programming question. maybe on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best place to start is A List Apart's [article on responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). That should show you the basic principles so you can go and build something.

The [final example site](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html) should look good regardless of screen size.